# How to model semistructured data in Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, modeling

I have an agriculture related data that I need to model in java.to mention how the data looks in a nutshell the data is collection of attributes which are collected whenever a new plant variety is produced. Currently the plants I want to model their data are around 135 grouped into 9 groups. The problem I am facing during the modeling process is that every plant has its own attributes that it doesn't share with others and also it have few attributes similar to other plants and there is also some difference in attributes of the same plant released in the same year which makes it difficult to restrict the amount of fields I tried to include in the class.[image: sample data]

For example the attributes shown in the red might not be included in other variety or might be included adding other attributes it is not possible to know exactly which attributes can be there or not. The other problem is that some attributes similar to the one shown in the blue rectangle has range values.
What I have tried was to list down every possible attributes by looking over 24 books I have and having unique attributes making them into classes for every plant and extracting values which have ranges into other classes with min and max values and I ended up having over 200 classes which makes it very complicated to build a unified system that I can use to feed the data and retrieve info from it.

What is ur recommended approach to model the data the database I planned to use is mongodb since since some varieties may miss values which other varieties has. I am ready to move to other programming languages like python if I have to thanks.

Comment: well, it all depends on your use cases. But in general you don't need a specific model like class if you want to use mongo db you can just use Map<String,String> for your attributes and mongo will just recive/produce a json document

Comment: I do need the data to retrieve info like crops that grow at certain altitude or released in certain year and similar.